# Call object method in Python object with __getattr__

Tags: python, magic-methods

I've added `__getattr__(self, name)` to an object which is allowing me to access `__dict__` and return properties but I can no longer call object methods.

I've tried all sorts of combinations with __ magic methods and getattr() but nothing seems to prevent `maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object`

This is the current function. Note: "values" rather than dict is relevant for the object in the future, so I've avoided **dict** for now.

```
class ParentClass():
   def __getattr__(self, prop):
        if prop not in getattr(self, "properties"):
           return # DO something here to get method, I think - self.__get__(prop)
        return getattr(self, "properties")[prop]

class SubClass():
    pass
```

Any advice would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Well, `getattr(self, "values")` will always call `__getattr__(self, prop)`, so you have an infinite recursion… You need to use `super(self, MyClass).__getattr__(value)` or something similar.

Comment: Is `__getattribute__(self, name)`  in the same class?

Comment: Sorry, changed it to what I thought was meaningful. Updated with properties instead. Now behaves as tested.

Comment: @MikeMüller Updated the code. I'm calling a method from a sub class

Comment: It seems you are mixing up `__getattr__` and `__getattribute__` here.

Comment: Where is your `__getattribute__`? I only see  `__getattr__`.

Comment: @MikeMüller The description mentioned the wrong magic method. There's only a __getattr__ method in the parent object and no magic methods in the sub class

Comment: Your code works for me. You need to add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting Rafe Kettler in its [Guide to Python's magic methods](https://github.com/RafeKettler/magicmethods):

> `__getattribute__(self, name)` After all this, `__getattribute__` fits in pretty well with its
>   companions `__setattr__` and `__delattr__`. However, I don’t recommend you use it.
>   `__getattribute__` can only be used with new-style classes (all classes are new-style in
>   the newest versions of Python, and in older versions you can make a class new-style
>   by subclassing object. It allows you to define rules for whenever an attribute’s value
>   is accessed. It suffers from some similar infinite recursion problems as its partners-incrime
>   (this time you call the base class’s `__getattribute__` method to prevent this).
>   It also mainly obviates the need for `__getattr__`, which, when `__getattribute__` is
>   implemented, only gets called if it is called explicitly or an AttributeError is raised.
>   This method can be used (after all, it’s your choice), but I don’t recommend it because it
>   has a small use case (it’s far more rare that we need special behavior to retrieve a value
>   than to assign to it) and because it can be really difficult to implement bug-free.

I think you can avoid magic methods, by doing this:

```
class ParentClass(object):
    def __getattr__(self, prop):
        if prop in self.properties:
            return self.properties[prop]
        # the property is missing, do something else...
```